# string to tabular python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a NLP tagged string in this format:

`ABC [B-ORG] Funding [I-ORG] Angela [I-PER] Ham [I-PER] Stockholm [S-LOC] Chief Executive Officer \n Head of XYZ [E-ORG]`

I need to comeup with a df output for it -

```
 Text        Label
 ABC Funding ORG
 Angela Ham  PER
 Stockholm   LOC
 Chief Executive Officer 
 Head of
 XYZ         ORG
```

Please consider - 
1. that there are untagged strings too like Chief Executive Officer Head of" in the above and they should retain.
2. There are new line characters(\n) in the string which should result in next row in the df.
3. Grouping of same consecutive labeled text like "ABC Funding" needs to occur unless there is a \n between the strings.

Answer (score 0):

1. use regex to extract the parts (there are different ways to do that) and insert to dataframe

```
    import re
    ner_parts = re.findall('([\w ]+)\s(?:\[\w-([\w]+)]|\n)', string)
    df = pd.DataFrame(ner_parts, columns=['text', 'label'])

                           text label
    0                       ABC   ORG
    1                   Funding   ORG
    2                    Angela   PER
    3                       Ham   PER
    4                 Stockholm   LOC
    5   Chief Executive Officer      
    6               Head of XYZ   ORG
```

2. group consecutive labels

```
groups = (~(df.label == df.label.shift())).cumsum()
groups.name = 'group' #just for nice look at the end result
groups

0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    4
6    5
```

3. group text together

```
def merge_text(group):
    return pd.Series([group['text'].str.cat(), group['label'].iat[0]],index=['text', 'label'])

df.groupby(groups).apply(merge_text)

                           text label
group                                
1                   ABC Funding   ORG
2                    Angela Ham   PER
3                     Stockholm   LOC
4       Chief Executive Officer      
5                   Head of XYZ   ORG
```

Comment: This does get close.However, the "Chief Executive Officer " is not coming after the regrex. Also "Head of" should be just another row and not merged with XYZ.